# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: works_attributes, educations_attributes in rails nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am trying to save the model called applicant with nesting to work and education model. When saving the model, I am getting:

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: works_attributes, educations_attributes error.

I am also getting an error for an undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass. I am using Rails 3.2.

My model code:

```
applicant.rb

class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :location, :email, :mob_no, :alternative_no, :linkedin, :facebook, :twitter, :message, :resume, :job_id
  has_many :works, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :educations, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :works, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :educations, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

end


work.rb

class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :applicant_id, :company_name, :description, :end_month, :end_year, :start_month, :start_year, :title
  belongs_to :applicant
end


education.rb

class Education < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :applicant_id, :end_month, :end_year, :institution_name, :major, :start_month, :start_year, :title
  belongs_to :applicant
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including work and education attributes like this ..

```
class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :works_attributes, educations_attributes
```

Comment: its working, but the work model data is not saved to the data base

Comment: To save the work model data you have to pass the values in your applicant controllers create method

Comment: how i have to pass them...can you help me for that

Comment: i have also tried nested_form gem of rails, i am trying the same code as given on github page for nested_form gem. But in views , where i am using fields_for task, its giving me error :wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)
Extracted source (around line #56):

53:           </div>
54: 
55:           <div class="four-fifth last">
56:             <%= f.fields_for :works do |task_form| %>
57:             <%= task_form.text_field :title %>
58:             <%= task_form.link_to_remove "Remove this task" %>
59:             <% end %>

Comment: my controller code : def newFillProfile
    if Job.find_by_id(params[:id]).nil?
      render_404
    else
     job = Job.find_by_job_url(params[:id])
    applicant = Applicant.new
     2.times { applicant.works.build }
     2.times { applicant.educations.build }
    end
  end
  
  def createProfile
     applicant = Applicant.new(params[:applicant])
    applicant.save
  end .............. i have removed @ from the instance vairables as this editor not allowing me to write it here